# Why are objects appearing at different places on AIR Android?

Tags: flash, actionscript, air

The problem I am facing has started to really frustrate me. And anyone who'd help me solve it , would be like a saint for me.

I have been working on an AIR Android application for about 8 months now. I have written around 15k lines of code spread across 60 classes.  Everything is working perfectly when I test it on windows, but when I install the app on my device (Samsung Galaxy S4), some things don't work properly. Some objects appear at different places while others don't appear at all. There is other weird stuff as well.  And when I set the render mode to GPU, things go way crazier. I mean i can't really see much of the app.

To make you understand this problem I have decided to make videos of my app on pc and on my device with gpu and cpu rendering.

ON WINDOWS : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ncknm-_7BN8

As you can see, everything is working pretty good here.

ON ANDROID(CPU): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VFPg3vxSOw

- **First Problem**

  In the "Today" screen, when I tap on the "+" button. The popup windows is doesn't appear where it's supposed to. While some of the code is working, some is not. Such as, the colors are not changing. Here is the show() function that makes the popup appear.

  ```
  public function show():void
  {
    homeCurrency = sett.xmlDB.HomeCurrency.@name;
    this.visible = true;
    TweenMax.to(this, .4, { alpha:1} );

    if(AirNetworkInfo.networkInfo.isConnected())
    {
      if (homeCurrency != getCurrentCurrency())
      {
          curr_txt.text = "Entered value will be converted from " +   getCurrentCurrency() + " to " + homeCurrency;
      }
      else {

          curr_txt.text = "";
      }
  }
  else
  {
      curr_txt.text = "";
  }

  changeColors();
  ```

  }

The function changeColors() which is supposed to well ,change the colors doesn't work. Here is how changeColors() looks:

```
private function changeColors():void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < allObjects.length; i++)
        {
            TweenMax.to(allObjects[i], .2, {tint:_main.settings.xmlDB.Theme.@name} );
        }

        curr_txt.textColor = _main.settings.xmlDB.Theme.@name;
    }
```

- **Problem 2**
  The No Connection popup doesn't appear at all. The animations are working but no popup.
- **Problem 3**
  The second problem is in the "Manage Loans Screen". This , I have no idea what is going on here. I hope someone can explain it to me.
- **Problem 4**
  In the "Settings", when I tap on the country button to choose a country. Nothing happens. The list is supposed to show up but nothing happens.

ON ANDROID (GPU): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcbdTgfT6GM

Well, you saw what happens here. Can anyone explain? Help me?  I'd really really be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1 . Are you loading XML settings into your app? if so, maybe the XML isn't being packaged successfully.

For the other problems, have you used debug mode when testing on Android to see any errors in the output log?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried remote debugging in the mobile device? Connecting your app to the flash/air debugger in the PC.  I am on a mobile so I have not seen the video, but all kinds of filters (including blurr and color filters you seem to be using do not work in gpu mode- they work in direct mode though). I would not recommend using any filters in gpu mode, even wrapped in TweenMax. Alpha is ok.